# Confusion regarding stability & step response?

Tags: matlab, stability, step-response

Let's say we have a system (for example an integrator) whose step response has a negative slope as shown by the MATLAB code below:

```
clc;clear ;close all
R=47*10^3
C=1*10^-7
num1=[-1]
den=[R*C 0]
sys1=tf(num1,den)
num2=[1]
sys2=tf(num2,den)
subplot 211
pzmap(sys1)
title('pole zero map for pure integrator, with -1 in numerator')
subplot 212
pzmap(sys2)%plotting poles and zeros
title('pole zero map for integrator, with +1 in numerator')
figure
subplot 211
step(sys1)
title('step response for pure integrator, with -1 in numerator')
subplot 212
step(sys2)
title('step response for integrator, with +1 in numerator')
```

`sys1` is an ideal integrator and we know that ideal integrators are stable systems.

But what if we replace `-1` in the numerator with `1` (`sys2`): then the step response slope will be positive: is `sys2` unstable because of the positive slope?

Comment: What do you mean by "pure" integrator, an ideal integrator? Anyway, changing the sign of a transfer function will definitely not change its stability properties.

Comment: An ideal integrator with a transfer function of $1/s$ is only marginally stable since it has  pole at $s=0$ and infinite gain at DC.  That's why the step response of the integrator grow to inifinity

Comment: @MattL. please check updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ideal integrator is not [BIBO-stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability), i.e., there are bounded input signals which result in an unbounded output. A step at the input is such a signal.

Clearly, changing the sign of the transfer function doesn't make any difference. In both cases, the system is not BIBO-stable.

As mentioned in a comment, the ideal integrator is only *marginally* stable because it has a pole on the imaginary axis. This makes it BIBO-unstable. Any DC at the input will result in an output signal with linearly increasing magnitude.